# Memory leaks in pushViewController and (I think) coming back from a GCD queue

Tags: ios, memory-management, viewcontroller, grand-central-dispatch

I'm having some trouble with memory leaks on one of my view controllers. From my main view controller, I'm pushing my settings view controller like so:

```
-(IBAction)launchSettings {
    SettingsViewController *svc = [[SettingsViewController alloc] init];
    svc.title = @"title of app";

    //this actually adds a back button for the next vc pushed
    self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = [[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Back" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:nil action:nil] autorelease];

    [[self navigationController] pushViewController:svc animated:YES]; // <--Instruments says leak is here
    [svc release];

    if (AdsAreEnabled) {
        ADBannerView *adBanner = SharedAdBannerView;
        adBanner.delegate = nil;
    }    
}
```

So, when I initially push the view controller, I have no leaks. The view controller uses a GCD queue to load up my In-App Purchase store, and when I hit the "back" button I've created above to pop it off the stack, that's when a crapload of leaks show up in Instruments. A bunch are showing up in the line of code where I push the view controller, which makes no sense to me since I immediately release it.

A couple other leaks are only leaking in main, either `NSCFstring`s, `SKProduct` and `SKProductInternal`, all of which I think are only brought up in the GCD queue. Here's where instruments is telling me the problem is:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
    int retVal = UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, nil); // <-- Instruments says leak is here
    [pool release];
    return retVal;
}
```

Here's my code where I call GCD, in its own method that gets called during `viewDidLoad` of the `SettingsViewController`:

```
if ([iapManager canMakePurchases]) {
    // Display a store to the user.
    iapTableView.sectionFooterHeight = 0;
    iapTableView.rowHeight = 50;
    iapTableView.scrollEnabled = NO;
    //init sectionNames here to avoid leakage.
    sectionNames = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"Get Rid of Ads!", nil];
    [spinner startAnimating];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(reloadStore) name:kInAppPurchaseManagerProductsFetchedNotification object:iapManager];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(reloadStore) name:kTransactionCompleted object:iapManager];
    //Run this in seperate thread to avoid UI lockup
    dispatch_queue_t store_check = dispatch_queue_create("see if store is available", NULL);
    dispatch_async(store_check, ^ {
        [iapManager loadStore];
    });
    dispatch_release(store_check); 
}
```

I'm a little stumped as to what I've done wrong here - I use exactly the same technique to load up a different view controller and it doesn't leak, and I can't figure out how to tell if/where my GCD stuff is leaking - everything's been analyzed repeatedly and comes out clean. I remove my observer from the Notification Center in SVC's `dealloc` so it's not that. I made sure to remove the transaction observer in my IAP manager's `dealloc`, so it's not that.

Any suggestions? Anything else you'd need to know to help me figure out where I've gone so terribly terribly wrong here?

*Edited to add: I release sectionNames in SVC's `dealloc` method, so that's not it either.*

*Edit 2: I tried auto-`releasing` svc when I `alloc` it (and getting rid of the corresponding `release`) but I'm still getting the same leaks.*

Comment: `sectionNames` is a leak, either call release first or use a property and then an autoreleased array. Remember `viewDidLoad` can be called multiple times.

Comment: Nope, no dice. I was releasing `sectionNames` in `dealloc` since I needed to access it again when I was loading up the rest of the tableView that shows the store, but for some reason I was just using an ivar and not a property. I added it as a property in addition to see if that fixed it, and at first it looked like it had, but nope, still getting that leak.

Comment: That is not going to fix your problem but that is still a leak, even though you are releasing it in `dealloc` you still need to release before you assign it again.

Comment: I'm a little confused - as far as I can see, it's only assigned once, right here. Then I just access it again when I reload the tableView's data (at which point it's just being read for the sectionHeader for a `UITableViewStyleGrouped` tableView. I'd release it if I were giving it a different name later on, but I just give it the name here so the name shows up while a spinner I've got going while the store loads is spinning away.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I finally figured it out with some troubleshooting help from a friend - for some reason I forgot you still have to `release` an `IBOutlet` ivar even if you haven't set it up as a `property` (for some reason I thought an `IBOutlet` `autoreleased` if it wasn't a property, which is not true), and once I had the proper releases in `dealloc`, all my leaks magically went away.

Duh. Another thing to add to my Idiot Checklist, I suppose. :)

Thanks for the suggestions, guys!

Answer (score 0):

First of all, in "launchSettings". You have initialized the UIBarButtonItem by "alloc and init" which makes its retain count = 1 but you haven't released it.

You should realize that those properties are retaining the values passed to them. So you could have `autoreleased` it.

I should say that this action isn't needed as the back button is already put for you.

Second, in the last code snippet, you did the same `sectionsName`.

Comment: Hi Mohannad, actually, the UIBarButtonItem is already `autoreleased`, if you look to the end of that line of code. I did it this way so it would actually read "Back" instead of the default of the title of the previous view controller (which is pretty long). I will add a note about releasing sectionNames in `dealloc` as well, since I did that and it seems to be what a couple people think is the problem.